# Search Filter blocks in online shops

Tags: search, filtering, web-deployment

I see on many sites search-filter block. And i can't to find this plugin. Please, tell me which plugin used here?

Examples of block:
http://www.sotmarket.ru/category/mobiles.html

http://market.yandex.ru/guru.xml?CMD=-RR=9,0,0,0-VIS=70-CAT_ID=432460-EXC=1-PG=10&hid=91013